# How can I link two PS4s without internet?

Tags: ps4

I cannot get my 2 PlayStation 4s linked to play  7 Days to Die. I don't have internet and I'm trying not to use split screen. I have cables, but I'm not sure what to do with them.

Comment: Do you have a local area network (LAN) to try and play over? Not sure how 7 Days to Die will respond to that though.

Answer (score 1):

For this game, if you want to play together and maintain separate screens, you'll need to play online. Otherwise, this game supports offline local co-op splitscreen. On Co-Optimus, it states under 7 Days to Die:

> System link or LAN play is not supported.

Please see the complete list of co-op features at Co-Optimus [here](http://www.co-optimus.com/game/4169/playstation-4/7-days-to-die.html).